# " Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell'...to 'UILabel' "

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

This is the error i'm getting. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but i'm having a bit of trouble with it. I updated this thread to add the code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 5
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckListItem", for: indexPath)

    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        label.text = "Walk the dog"
    case 1:
        label.text = "Brush my teeth"
    case 2:
        label.text = "Learn iOS development"
    case 3:
        label.text = "Soccer practice"
    case 4:
        label.text = "Eat ice cream"
    default:
        label.text = "Nothing"
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you set the tag on the label or the cell? Also, you really should not be working with tags. Subclass your cell, and set an outlet between the label and a property on the cell subclass.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Please copy and paste relevant code into your question as text. It makes it easier to read and easier to reference when answering.

Comment: Thanks. I had to set the tag on the label, NOT the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `viewWithTag(_:)` function does:

> Returns the view’s nearest descendant (including itself) with a
>   specific tag, or nil if no subview has that tag.

So what you're getting back is the object itself *as well as* its nearest descendant. It looks like you're just trying to set the text inside the cell, so what you can do is just change your code to this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckListItem", for: indexPath)

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = "Walk the dog"
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = "Brush my teeth"
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = "Learn iOS development"
    case 3:
        cell.textLabel.text = "Soccer practice"
    case 4:
        cell.textLabel.text = "Eat ice cream"
    default:
        cell.textLabel.text = "Nothing"
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working through iOS Apprentice series and just encountered the same problem as you did.

I think you might want to check where you attach the tag:1000 to in Main.storyboard -- if you're failing because of this reason, you have probably attached the tag to the UITableViewCell instead of the Label (of type UILabel) under Content View.